# Find next value

Tags: c#

My goal is to write a small application in C# to control a legacy device that has no software. The Device is controlled via RS232 interface.

For setting a multiplication factor, it is possible to send a "coarse" value from a set of possible values:

```
string coarseList[7] = 
{
10,
20,
40,
100,
200,
1000
};
```

Additionally, the coarse values, are multiplicated by a fine factor, which can be `0.4  to 1.0` in steps with resolution of `0.000244`. The mulitplication factor / fine setting has to be send in 12-bit notation e.g

```
uint16_t lowest_fine = 1638  //factor of 0.4
uint16_t highest_fine = 4095 //factor of 1.00
```

To calculate the final value the following calculation can be done:

```
uint16_t fineSetting = 1640;
double fineFactor = 0.4 + ((fineSetting-1638)*0.000244);   //equals 0.400488
double coarseGain = coarseList[1]; //equals 20
double finalGain = coarseGain * fineFactor;  //equals 8.00976 (20*0.400488)
```

Now my goal is, to provide an user-friendly and safe input for setting the values, and then have find the correct settings. The code should find the next possible value from an user-input field, for example `8.000978` would be `8.00976` and therefor the values of `20`, and `1640`

I've already came so far to select highest and lowest values, and also some that are exactly in the list:

```
double userInput = getUserInput();

if(userInput < 4){
 coarse = 10;
 fine = 1638;
}

if(userInput >1000){
 coarse = 1000;
 fine = 4095;
}

for (uint8_t i=0; i<7 ;i++){
 if(coarseList[i]==userInput){
   coarse=coarseList[i];
   fine = 4095;
   break;
 }
}
```

But now I'm struggling to determine the values for any given setting, for example `40.51245` or `125` or `95.124875`

The Language I'm using is C#. How can I realize a function that calculates the correct values for me?

Also, the closest value should be selected, for example, if the input is 18, the coarse should be 20, even it might be possible to reach this value with a coarse of 40!

Comment: So, you're asking for the reverse of the code block beginning with `uint16_t fineSetting` - the user will type a number between 4 and 1000, and you'll reverse it to find a coarse and near fine setting?

Comment: Correct, also see my edit.

Comment: Seems to me like you'll have to divide the user input by every coarse to see whether the result will end up being in range for the fine, and you might have multiple candidates, but other than that it's just a bit of maths.. Heck, even a brute forcing approach looking for the largest number not greater than the user input would be done with in milliseconds..

Comment: why do you declare an array of string when numbers like 1000 are clearly not strings

Comment: @phuclv, because they are sent in string format later, for example "$C01000A\r" for the setting of "1000".

Comment: then why initialize it with integers instead of strings `"1000"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the absolute lowest error, you can use LINQ to find the possibilities and then order by error and select.

The following selects by smallest error and then by smallest coarse factor, but you could change the order for other criteria:

```
var lowest_fine = 1638; // factor of 0.4
var highest_fine = 4095; // factor of 1.00

var target = 8.000978;

var ansAbs = coarseList
                .Select(c => new { c, f = Math.Floor(4095 * target / c) })
                .Where(cf => lowest_fine <= cf.f && cf.f <= highest_fine)
                .SelectMany(cf => new[] {
                                new { cf.c, cf.f, err = Math.Abs(cf.c * cf.f / 4095 - target) },
                                new { cf.c, f = cf.f+1, err = Math.Abs(cf.c * (cf.f+1) / 4095 - target) }
                            })
                .OrderBy(cfe => cfe.err)
                .ThenBy(cfe => cfe.c)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want to select by the closest value greater than the target, this code filters out negative errors then selects by minimum error and minimum coarse value:

```
var ansPlus = coarseList
                .Select(c => new { c, f = Math.Floor(4095 * target / c) })
                .Where(cf => lowest_fine <= cf.f && cf.f <= highest_fine)
                .SelectMany(cf => new[] {
                                new { cf.c, cf.f, err = cf.c * cf.f / 4095 - target },
                                new { cf.c, f = cf.f+1, err = cf.c * (cf.f+1) / 4095 - target }
                            })
                .Where(cfe => cfe.err >= 0)
                .OrderBy(cfe => cfe.err)
                .ThenBy(cfe => cfe.c)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

These answers will be `null` if there is no mathematical match, you can use `if` tests for `target` values out of range (e.g. `< 4` or `> 1000`).

NOTE: Your example is wrong: a better pair is `(10,3276)` for an absolute error of ~0.000978 or if you must be above, `(10,3277)` for an error of ~0.001464.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. Yes you are correct about my example